# Deploying approval workflow in 2010 as wsp?

Tags: 2010, workflow, solution-package

I am creating a sharepoint 2010 designer workflow (Approval). I want to deploy this to the live server for the project I am on. Is it possible to produce a wsp package? How can I deploy this unit of customisation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to create **Reusable Workflows**. It basically allows you to save the workflow as a template resulting in a .wsp file which ultimately can be brought to Visual Studio for deployment.

Check out this excellent blog from Geoff Varosky for step by step details - http://sharepointyankee.com/2010/12/11/options-for-deploying-reusable-workflows-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Great, so I can build a wsp. That isn't bound to the local server, correct?

Comment: yes...check the article and follow the steps..it should work.